# How do I sqlmock an empty set using golang go-sqlmock

Tags: mysql

I want to test some SQL like:

```
select name from user where uid = ?
```

This is ok, I can mock it like this way:

```
rows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{“name"}).AddRow(“info")

did = "1234"
mock.ExpectPrepare(“select name from user where uid = ?").ExpectQuery().
       WithArgs(uid).
       WillReturnRows(rows)
```

But I want to mock the testing in which the user table does not have this uid — the select will return a Empty set

```
mysql> select * from user where uid = “887";
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

How can I mock an empty table?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
rows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{“name"})
```

not addRow

Comment: You could also not assign the NewRows() to an unused variable `rows`